# How to combine two dataframes into one pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to create a combination of concentrations of two chemicals for an experiment. Since I want to see which combination of both is the best I want to create an overview how much I need to add of each at a given concentration. So far I managed to create two pivot_tables/dataframes of each but Im somehow don't get them to merge into one.

So I've tried this approach so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


array_CinA = np.array([0,125,250,500,1000])
array_Aceto = np.array([0,100,200,400,800])
vol_cina = [0, 5, 10, 20, 40]
vol_as = [0, 2, 4,8,16]

array = np.array(np.meshgrid(array_CinA,array_Aceto)).T.reshape(-1,2)

df = pd.DataFrame({"CinnamonicAcid":array_CinA,
                   "Acetosyringone":array_Aceto,
                   "VolCinA": vol_cina,
                   "VolAS": vol_as})

pivtab = df.pivot_table(index="CinnamonicAcid", columns="Acetosyringone", values=["VolCinA", "VolAS"])
#pivtab.to_excel
print(pivtab)
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
               VolAS                      VolCinA                       
Acetosyringone   0    100  200  400   800     0    100   200   400   800
CinnamonicAcid                                                          
0                0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN     0.0  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
125              NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN  5.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
250              NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN
500              NaN  NaN  NaN  8.0   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN  20.0   NaN
1000             NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  16.0     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  40.0
```

My desired output would be something like this:

[image: Output from Code]

Comment: Your input data doesn't have a result for (for example) 125 CinnamonicAcid and 400 Acetosyringone, so why do you expect these values to have an entry in the pivot table? If you want to get a pivot table with entries for every combination of CinnamonicAcid and Acetosyringone, you have to provide input data that has a value for every combination.

Comment: Also, what is the reason for creating the variable `array`? You never use this variable after creating it.

Comment: Ahhh the array is a relict from a previous attempt in order to get the combinations of both. And that's exactly my problem. I don't know how to provide the input data for it via code. The only alternative would be to manually input the input data. But in the end, I would like to make it a scaleable code, where I just need to change my concentrations and amounts so it would give me the results since I have to do a lot of testing.

Comment: What I usually do for data entry is use Excel for data entry then read the resulting csv or xls file into a DataFrame using read_csv() or read_excel().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) for new 2d arrays and divide them, then pass to DataFrame constructor:

```
array_CinA = np.array([0,125,250,500,1000])
array_Aceto = np.array([0,100,200,400,800])
vol_cina = [0, 5, 10, 20, 40]
vol_as = [0, 2, 4,8,16]

shape = (len(array_Aceto), len(array_CinA))

arr = np.core.defchararray.add(np.array(vol_cina).astype(str), '/')[:, None]

a1 = np.broadcast_to(arr, shape)
a2 = np.broadcast_to(np.array(vol_as).astype(str), shape)

df = (pd.DataFrame(np.core.defchararray.add(a1, a2), index=array_CinA, columns=array_Aceto))
print (df)
       0     100   200   400    800
0      0/0   0/2   0/4   0/8   0/16
125    5/0   5/2   5/4   5/8   5/16
250   10/0  10/2  10/4  10/8  10/16
500   20/0  20/2  20/4  20/8  20/16
1000  40/0  40/2  40/4  40/8  40/16
```

Comment: Thanks so with broadcast i could get them together. However, I don't want to divide them. The / was just to separate the two numbers. I would like to basically combine the two integers into one string consisting of both integers. Is there a function doing that? or do I then have to create a loop?

Comment: @Teigsta - answer was edited.

Comment: @Teigsta thought my answer was more intuitive and I answered(correctly) faster than the guy with 773k reputation.. anyway just would like to have some feedback on my answer

Answer (score 0):

The below code  should be what you are after.

I am using product function from intertools library to create the full data. Then I am just converting to string type so that numpy doesn't get confused and I reshape it. Finally I am producing a dataframe providing index names and column names.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

array_CinA = np.array([0, 125, 250, 500, 1000])
array_Aceto = np.array([0, 100, 200, 400, 800])
vol_cina = [0, 5, 10, 20, 40]
vol_as = [0, 2, 4, 8, 16]


# creating full data
my_product = list(product(vol_cina, vol_as))
# converting to str
my_product_str = [str(a) for a in my_product]
# converting to np array
my_product_str_np = np.array(my_product_str)
# reshaping
my_product_str_np = my_product_str_np.reshape(len(vol_cina), len(vol_as))
# producing final data
df = pd.DataFrame(my_product_str_np, index=array_CinA, columns=array_Aceto)
df.index.name="CinnamonicAcid"
df.columns.name="Acetosyringone"
print(df)
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I actually used both answers. And I have to admit that for my future project I sticked to your way since it was more convenient. Thank you very much for it. I wish I could give you a thumbs up or anything for it.

Comment: Thank you! Feels really nice to know you used my answer! Good luck with future projects. If you get enough reputation one day, you can give me an upvote